# Whats the right way to handle (deeply nested) functors?

Tags: haskell, functor, purescript

I have the following simple code

```
import Data.String.Regex
import Data.Array

last <$> match someRegex "   1"
```

where

```
match someRegex "   1"
```

returns something like

```
Just ([Just ("   1"),Just ("   "),Just ("1")])
```

and

```
last <$> match someRegex "   1"
```

returns something like

```
Just (Just (Just ("   1")))
```

Now I have a deeply nested Maybe. Which makes it sort of hard to work with (even using functors).
I have written myself a pair of helper functions - but I am sort of unhappy with that. It somehow doesn't feel right.

```
extract j = do
    case j of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just a -> a
extract2 jj = extract $ extract jj
```

And then using it like this

```
extract2 $ last <$> match someRegex "   1"
```

Is there a better/idiomatic way to do such things in Purescript/Haskell?

Comment: If you don't want to join yet, but want to change it, remember that fmap is composable: `fmap . fmap :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)`, `fmap . fmap . fmap :: (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h) => (a -> b) -> f (g (h a)) -> f (g (h b))`

Comment: hmm my question was more if there is a way to avoid this nesting in the first place

Comment: With `Maybe` there is little interesting information encoded in the multiple layers, but that might not be the case with other functors (e.g. you could use `fmap . fmap . fmap` to map over a doubly nested list while preserving all of its structure).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the `join` function:

http://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-control/0.3.0/docs/Control.Bind#d:join

`join` collapses two layers of a structure down to a single layer, combining any effects. In the case of `Maybe`, that means that the resulting value will not be `Nothing` only if both layers were not `Nothing`.

Comment: so basically you are saying my `extract` function is some variant of `join` and that is the way things are being handled? duh! Isn't there a way (conceptually) to avoid that deeply nesting in the first place?

Comment: One way is to notice that `join (map f x)` is the same as `x >>= f` by the `Monad` laws, so you could say `match someRegex "   1" >>= last` and save yourself a `join`.

Comment: `match` returns two layers of `Maybe` because of the multiple ways in which the JS version can fail, so at least one `join` is necessary if you care about everything being successful.